# Difficulty with starting 2005 Kia Sedona

Tags: starting, kia, intermittent-problems, sedona

I have a 2005 Kia Sedona. About 2 months ago I went to start it, and it cranked but didn't start until the 3rd time, and the engine jumped? Since then I have had the problem of it cranking but not starting only a few times but no problem for the last 2 weeks until this morning it took me 3 cranks to start it ! I live in SC and the temperature has really dropped in the last 2 days ! May the weather have anything to do with it starting ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of variables to suspect, but the one that comes to mind is a fuel filter.  If the filter gets so dirty that it restricts fuel flow thereby adversely affecting the pressure that can cause this very problem.  If you haven't done so in awhile, it probably wouldn't hurt to start there then if your still having issues do a fuel pump pressure test.  Might also clean out the intake near the throttle plate. An air leak due to dirt can cause a lean mixture that could defeat the added fuel dispensed to simulate a choke on a carbureted engine.